# phonegap image download error code 3

Tags: android, cordova, download, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

i am trying to download image from url ,by using phonegap file transfer plugin download method
but always gets error code: 3,
here's my code :

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs)
{
    // create the download directory is doesn't exist
    fs.root.getDirectory('download', { create: true });

    //  save file in .. download
    var filePath = fs.root.fullPath + 'download/' + url.split('/').pop();
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(decodeURIComponent("http://phonegap.com/uploads/artwork/Build-Bot-Preview.png"));
    filePath="file:///sdcard"+filePath;


    fileTransfer.download(uri,filePath,function(entry)
    {
        alert("Successfully downloaded file, full path is " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error)
    {
        alert("Some error " + error.code + " for " + url);
    }, 
    false);
});
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in a new created phonegap project and it is working for me. I get [an alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUQeC.png) that says it was successful.

**index.js:**

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    var url = "http://animalia-life.com/image.php?pic=/data_images/dog/dog1.jpg";

    window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs)
    {
        // create the download directory is doesn't exist
        fs.root.getDirectory('download', { create: true });

        //  save file in .. download
        var filePath = fs.root.fullPath + 'download/' + url.split('/').pop();
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI(decodeURIComponent("http://phonegap.com/uploads/artwork/Build-Bot-Preview.png"));
        filePath="file:///sdcard"+filePath;

        fileTransfer.download(uri,filePath,function(entry)
        {
            alert("Successfully downloaded file, full path is " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error)
        {
            alert("Some error " + error.code + " for " + url);
        }, 
        false);
    });

},
```

I hope it helps. At least you know the code is working now.

**EDIT:**

Do you have in the access origin line your config.xml?:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

**EDIT: EDIT:**

I declare the plugins with these lines in my config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" version="3.0.0" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" version="1.3.0" />
```

Comment: created new project and added the same code still not working.
same error code :3 in android

Comment: yes i do have,
Here's my config.xml


`<content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package"       value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>`

Comment: I have to ask this. Have you switched on the WiFi connection on your device? I also replaced my config.xml with your config.xml, but I didn't get an error. The error you have is a connection error by the way.

Comment: yes i have checked my connection before downloading, still not working same error code :3

Comment: When I went to build.phonegap.com and looked under the plugins tab of the app I created with your configuration I didn't saw any plugins.

Comment: i am using filetransfer.download plugin of phonegap. it is in the documentation. here's the link :
[link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)